# How to reduce landscape curvature?

Tags: distortion, field-curvature

My camera is a Nikon D610 which I used with a Sigma 12-24 wide angle lens. Can anyone recommend a software product to straighten up horizons with? I have attached an example where I have a curved lake horizon in my photograph but I don't want to destroy the sharpness of the image.

[image: landscape curvature]

Comment: There's no way to stretch things in post without giving up at least a bit of resolution. Just ask [Uncle Roger](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/01/you-can-correct-it-in-post-but/)

Answer (score 4):

I have not used the latest version, but DxO makes a database of a combination of body and lenses to correct some problems, like chromatic aberration, etc.

They also have a program to correct wide angle lenses deformations: https://www.dxo.com/dxo-viewpoint/

It has a 30-day trial.

---

Here is another program. A plug in for Photoshop.

http://richardrosenman.com/shop/lens-corrector-pro/

---

You can also use [Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/correcting-image-distortion-noise.html).

---

Paint shop pro has some [basic corrections](http://product.corel.com/help/PaintShop-Pro/540214299/Main/EN/Doc/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Corel-PaintShop-Pro-Correcting-lens-distortions.html&single=true) too.

---

Affinity Photo has some [automatic lens correction](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/31430-list-of-compatible-cameras-and-lenses-for-automatic-lens-correction/)s.

---

And you also have [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/perspective/en.shtml) (This program does so many things)

---

But yes, you will sacrifice some of the image data. With extreme corrections, you need to crop the image, all the stuff that does not fit in the new rectangle.

In the specific case of your image, you will be fine.

Comment: Thank you Rafael. You have given me much to study. Looks like Hugin will be a worth a good look as well as lens correction for the specific lens. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It's a lake.  It does not have a horizon on this picture (which would be a transition of water to heaven or at least of water to non-water adjacent landscape) as much as it has a shoreline.  The shoreline is curved.

Of course you may want to straighten the lines for artistic reasons rather than geometric ones.  You will sacrifice some subpixel amount of sharpness: that's not avoidable.  To make this not unnecessarily accumulative on top of other camera-internal geometric processing losses, you'll be best served starting with the RAW image and doing all geometric processing in one swoop.  A number of raw processing programs can do geometric correction of both camera and lens starting from profiled parameters, but if you want to straighten a shoreline, the profiled parameters will not be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do want to straighten the curve to remove distortion caused by the wide 12mm lens. It will be interesting to me to see if I like the finished result, as you say artistic.